# divide an array into multiple arrays, each array in which the number of units is determined by the size

Tags: ruby, arrays

For example,i have an array :[2,4,6,7,9,12,1],i want to divide it by the size [2,2,3]

the output that i want is:`[[2,4],[6,7],[9,12,1]]`

i have tried:

```
a=[2,4,6,7,9,12,1]
b=[2,2,3]
c=[]
b.each{|m|c<<a.shift(m)}
c
```

is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: If you found any of the answers helpful, please select the one that was most helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Enumerable#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-map):

```
a = [2,4,6,7,9,12,1]
b = [2,2,3]
c = b.map { |m| a.shift(m) }
c
# => [[2, 4], [6, 7], [9, 12, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The way looks correct, you can do it more succinctly using `map` instead of `each`:

```
c = b.map{|m| a.shift(m)}
```

Or, using `&method` shorthand:

```
c = b.map(&a.method(:shift))
# => [[2, 4], [6, 7], [9, 12, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways that do not destroy the original array, as `Array#shift` does:

```
a=[2,4,6,7,9,12,1]
b=[2,2,3]
```

*Method #1*

```
cum = 0
b.map { |n| a[cum..(cum+=n)-1] }
  #=> [[2, 4], [6, 7], [9, 12, 1]]
```

*Method #2*

```
cum = 0
b.map { |n| a.values_at(*(cum..(cum+=n)-1)) }
  #=> [[2, 4], [6, 7], [9, 12, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have:

```
r = [2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 12, 1]

s = [2, 2, 3].map do |e|
  r.shift(e)
end

p s
```

Output:

```
[[2, 4], [6, 7], [9, 12, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work

```
2.1.0 :029 > a=[2,4,6,7,9,12,1]
 => [2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 12, 1] 
2.1.0 :030 > b = [2,2,3]
 => [2, 2, 3] 
2.1.0 :031 > b.inject([]){|result, value| result << a.take(value) }
 => [[2, 4], [2, 4], [2, 4, 6]] 
2.1.0 :032 >
```